# ERROR: null value in column "master_field_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "master", name = "master_mapping")
public class MasterMapping extends AuditedEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "master_field_id")
    private MasterFields masterField;

    @JsonIgnore
    public MasterFields getMasterField() {
        return masterField;
    }

    public void setMasterField(MasterFields masterField) {
        this.masterField = masterField;
    }

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "master", name = "master_fields")
public class MasterFields extends AuditedEntity {

    private String label;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "masterField")
    private List<MasterMapping> mappedFields;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public List<MasterMapping> getMappedFields() {
        return mappedFields;
    }

    public void setMappedFields(List<MasterMapping> mappedFields) {
        this.mappedFields = mappedFields;
    }
}
```

and common class with id

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AuditedEntity {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;

   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
```

}

I'm trying to save MasterFields object with MasterMapping, but I'm getting error:

Hibernate: insert into master.master_fields (label) values (?)

Hibernate: select currval('master.master_fields_id_seq')

Hibernate: insert into master.master_mapping (master_field_id) values (?)

SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502

ERROR: null value in column "master_field_id" violates not-null constraint
  Details: Failing row contains (null).

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

I'm trying to save it to db with EntityManager.merge(). I see that hibernate can't get generated id from MasterFields object. How can fix it?

Comment: Try without using AuditedEntity. I wonder if the mappedsuperclass react well with the id code. And work from there.

Comment: @XavierBouclet No, I moved code from AuiditedEntity and it didn't help

Comment: Could you add the code where you save your object?

Comment: Have you tried EntityManager.insert() instead of EntityManager.merge()?

Comment: @XavierBouclet I just autowire EntityManager, populate MasterField and MasterMappings inside MasterField and use merge() method

Comment: @egallardo EntityManager doesn't have insert method

Comment: @user2452483 post code where you create and save entities... btw insert is done with persist()